# Support for non-concrete "iN" types in LLVM

Tags: types, llvm, specialization

I just wanted to know , I've searched everywhere in the documentation ,
but does LLVM have any support  for **non-concrete types** ?

By non-concrete I mean , type like "iN" until runtime and then probably a sort of monomorphization pass ( see example below ) can be run to concretize the "iN" types to something like "i56" depending on the runtime parameters.

I **do NOT** wish to use the LLVM ORC JIT API , which would simplify everything, but not something that I wish to use.

**Here is an example scenario for the transformation i need to apply.
(Please Note that the language below is a custom language for which Im trying to build a compiler in LLVM).**

( There can be many tricky cases but this is a basic example scenario.
I have considered constructing a SSA form for my custom language at AST level but I would like to explore any possible options in the LLVM IR before making my own custom SSA form )

```
Before Transformation - 

(bits(datasize )) AddWithCarry(Boolean a)
{ 
    integer datasize =if a
                    then 5;
                    else 9;

    bits(datasize) res ;

    return res;

}



(integer)main()
{
        test(argv[1]); // command line argument

}

//===============================


After Transformation

(bits(datasize)) AddWithCarry(Boolean a)
{ 
       if a
            then 
             bits(5) res ;
             return res;
       else  
             bits(9) res ;
             return res;


}


(integer)main()
{
        test(argv[1]); // command line argument

}
```

Answer (score 1):

No. LLVM IR is low-level, so all the types should be concrete. All the high-level transformations should be performed inside a frontend. If you'd need changes to be performed during the runtime, then some sort of JIT would be required.

Comment: I am aware of the usage of JIT , that would be much simpler. However , I need to do it without using the JIT so I was wondering if there was a way to do it without making a custom SSA for my custom language...

Comment: Sorry , I meant custom SSA form for the AST of my language.